# Amazon Payment agreement checkbox not working

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, checkbox, terms-and-conditions, amazon-payment

Checkbox for agree not work currently and always show this message. I think does this is javascript or Ajax conflict.

**Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.**